# how do I put iterative statements in useEffect?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

```
    useEffect(()=>{ 

        while(itemlen===0)
        {
                fire.database().ref().child(path)
            .on("value",
            (snapshot)=>{
              let item=snapshot.val()
              console.log(item)
              if(item!==null){
                let array=[];
                Object.
                keys(item)
                .forEach(i=>array.push(item[i]));
                setCard1(array);
            }
            console.log(item,"item")
            if(item!==null)
           { 
            console.log(Object.keys(item).length,"item length")
            itemlen=7  //length of object I get from valid result
            }
             else {itemlen=0}
            })
           } 
            console.log(itemlen,'itemlen') 
      },[prefVar]);
```

my code inside the for loop selects a random path and retrieve that path only problem is that sometimes the path is empty so I want to use while loop to iterate the code again until I get a valid path.

Problem is that my app freezes when it comes to this part and get stuck.I am guessing it is due while loop inside useEffect and code works fine without while loop but gives empty results somethimes.
Is there some better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an infinite loop so it's normal for it to stop.

You should `poll` the data source from time to time until you get your information.
This can be done from inside `useEffect`.

Try something like this

```
useEffect(()=>{
  const getData = () => {
    fire.database().ref().child(path)
        .on("value",
        (snapshot)=>{
          let item=snapshot.val()
          console.log(item)
          if(item!==null){
            let array=[];
            Object.
            keys(item)
            .forEach(i=>array.push(item[i]));
            setCard1(array);
         }
         console.log(item,"item")
         if(item!==null)
         { 
          console.log(Object.keys(item).length,"item length")
          itemlen=7  //length of object I get from valid result
          clearInterval(interval) //stop polling for results
         }
         else {itemlen=0}
        })
     }
    const interval = setInterval(getData, TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  },[prefVar]);
```

Notice the return statement from `useEffect`. This is important as the react component may be removed, so we need to cleanup `setInterval`.

TIMEOUT_INTERVAL is the time, in ms, to wait between calls.

Comment: This works but my data is constantly updating even after entering inside if block, is clearInterval correct?